How to get my own folder files using Drive API?
I found the Google Drive API Docs, and all of them speak about OAuth that will allow my users grant acces to THEIR account files, but I want to make available through API MY files. How can I do that? Additionally I'm using PHP and this library https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client
My current code
<?php 
use Google\Client;
use Google\Service\Drive;
$files = [];
try{
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google\Client();
$client->setApplicationName("MYNAME");
$client->setDeveloperKey("MYKEY"); 
$client->addScope(Drive::DRIVE);
$driveService = new Drive($client);
$pageToken = null;
do {
            $response = $driveService->files->listFiles(array(
                'q' => "mimeType='image/jpeg'",
                'spaces' => 'drive',
                'pageToken' => $pageToken,
                'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
            ));
            foreach ($response->files as $file) {
                printf("Found file: %s (%s)\n", $file->name, $file->id);
            }
            array_push($files, $response->files);

            $pageToken = $response->pageToken;
} while ($pageToken != null);
var_dump($files);
 } catch(Exception $e) {
       echo "Error Message: ".$e;
    }

?>


This returns to me insufficientFilePermissions.

The Google Books example doesn't represent user data and so is accessible using a key. For all Google Workspace services that represent user data (including your own), you must Authenticate with OAuth (to prevent others from accessing it).
